# Wordpress MySQL join _usermeta on _users

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm a total mysql dumby doing my first paid wordpress gig and I cant seem to figure out how to join the users and usermeta tables to get a friendly result that I can use in my MYSQL-> Frontend Table plugin. 
The users table layout is:

```
id | user_id | user     | password
------------------------------------
1  | 1       | x        | yyyyyy
2  | 2       | xx       | yyyyyy
3  | 3       | xxx      | yyyyyy
4  | 4       | xxxx     | yyyyyy
5  | 5       | xxxxx    | yyyyyy
6  | 6       | xxxxxx   | yyyyyy
```

And the usermeta table layout is:

```
id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
------------------------------------
1  | 1       | firstname| bob
2  | 1       | lastname | smith
3  | 1       | email    | bob@smith.com
4  | 1       | phone    | 123-456-7890
5  | 1       | Street   | first street
6  | 1       | City     | New York
.
.
.
25 | 2       |firstname | jane
```

The result I'm looking for would look like:

```
id | user_id     | name     | email   | phone  | street  |  city  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | x        | 
2  | 2           | xx       |
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

EDIT-----------
Ive gotten to here, where I cant seem to get past error 
"MySQL said: Unknown column 'u.ID' in 'on clause'"

```
select u.ID as name,
um.*
from wp_xxxxxx_users as u, wp_xxxxxx_usermeta as um
join (
   select um.umeta_id,
   max(case when meta_key='nickname' then meta_value end)as nickname,
   max(case when meta_key='first_name' then meta_value end)as first_name
from wp_xxxxxx_usermeta as um
group by um.umeta_id)
um on u.ID=um.umeta_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *Pivot*. Provided that the required meta_keys are known in advance, you can achieve this using condition aggregation.

Something like this:

```
select u.user as name,
    um.*
from users u
join (
    select user_id,
        max(case when meta_key = 'email' then meta_value end) as email,
        max(case when meta_key = 'phone' then meta_value end) as phone,
        ...
    from usermeta
    group by user_id
    ) um on u.user_id = um.user_id;
```

Comment: What do the u's and m's refer to?

Comment: @GavinDiAngelus - Those are aliases for tables/subqueries. Makes it easier to refer to different columns when multiple tables are in play.

Comment: @GavinDiAngelus - Take a look at this tutorial to understand more - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp